# What's the shortest regex that can match non-zero floating point numbers with any number of decimal places?

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, match

What's the shortest regex that can match non-zero floating point numbers with any number of decimal places?

It should accept numbers like

```
-1
-5.9652
-7.00002
-0.8
-0.0500
-0.58000
0.01
0.000005
0.9900
5
7.5
7.005
```

but reject constructions such as

```
.
.02
-.
-.996
0
-0
0.
-0.
-0.000
0.00
--
..
+
+0
+1
+.
+1.26
,etc
```

I do not need support for the scientific notation, with e , E and such.
The language I'm using is C#, by the way.

Comment: Ah, I smell a "my regex is shorter then yours" contest. The things geeks fight over... :)

Comment: `0.0` will be in which side? accept or reject?

Comment: You forgot to include `0.000` in your test cases, most of the early answers accept it, but it's still zero in my book. :)

Comment: How about 001.000? accept right?

Comment: I'm willing to pass `001.000` as accepted, provided the solution is short enough.

Comment: Allowing leading zeros will cause confusion, since they are almost universally disallowed.  By the same token, trailing zeros are almost always accepted (and can be significant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^-?(0\.\d*[1-9]|[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$
```

---

**EDIT** Updated to reflect new requirements (last decimals can be zero)

```
^-?(0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$
```

(Shorter than using lookahead: `^-?(0\.(?=[1-9])\d*|[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$`.)

---

**EDIT2** If e.g. `001.000` can pass

```
^-?(?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the regex specifics in C#.

Comment: Yet, fortunately, your syntax was correct. As an addendum, I would go for `^-?(0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$` instead, in order to preserve consistency of being able to enter final zeros after numbers in the (-1, 1) range too, not only after numbers that begin with a positive digit.

Comment: Almost: rejects 0.10. Add another `\d*` after the first `[1-9]`.

Comment: Yeah, I was not quite sure as to whether e.g. `0.10` should be rejected or not. I see now that I was less than consistent :)

Comment: @luvieere I think my l33t regex0rz skillz are pretty much exhausted by now :) 26 chars seems to be my best shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I always use:

`(\+|-)?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?`

Utilized in a PHP example:

```
<?php

$s= '1.234e4';

preg_match('~(\+|-)?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?~', $s, $m);
print_r($m);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.234e4
    [1] =>
    [2] => 1.234
    [3] => e4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-?(?!0)\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Note: Remember to put ^ $ if it's not done by your regexp matcher.

May I ask why the "shortest"? A pre-compiler RegExp or the same with non-matching groups could be faster. Also a test for zero could possibly be faster too.

Comment: I want the shortest as it will go someplace in a XAML file and I want to keep it as brief as possible.

Comment: A difference of 5-15 bytes matters enough to disregard performance and clarity?

Comment: Characters in a regexp don't matter much once it's compiled. A RegExp evaluator is a finite state machine. There are many way to improve a FSM graph, and that's what some compilers do.

In short, there is not a direct relation between the RegExp string length and it's evaluation speed.

Comment: I'm not concerned about speed, but about visual compactness. I wouldn't want I big regex in XAML, it's hard to follow.

Comment: What is the `!` sign? I've tested this and it doesn't work, it fails with 5.02 and many others...

Comment: `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead assertion.  At that point, the `...` expression must not match for the assertion to succeed.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: luvieere: Code-golf ("what's the shortest way to do ... regardless of other considerations") is **not** about making code that is easy to follow.  Code should be concise but not necessarily the shortest possible.  It definitely sounds like you won't be editing this regex often, so why do you care if it's 5 characters or 25?  Take a look at a language like APL, which definitely produced *short* (in terms of characters) programs.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#Examples

Comment: This matches 5.02 for me (not tested in C# though), lack of `(?!)` support might be your issue?  The `.` should've been escaped.  (That kind of error is easy to make when you worry about code size instead of other things... :P)

Comment: "That kind of error is easy to make" ... tell me about it! And easy to correct as well, just click edit and go right at it.

Comment: Incidentally, the `\.` only appeared as `.` because of formatting (fixed now).  This won't accept "-1. 5", or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider [these variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184).